# After loading osm data using osm2pgrouting how can I add my point data for kdijikstra

Tags: qgis, postgis, osm2pgsql, osm2pgrouting

I have imported osm data to postgis by osm2pgrouting. Now I want to add point data of my locations, to find distance from one point to multiple points through the osm ways data. I am new to pgrouting.

How can I create topology from these points to ways data.

=

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are asking. Are you asking how to find the nearest road segment from some point to some other point, where neither point is exactly on a road segment? Have you read [the docs](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.3/en/doc/index.html).

Comment: I previously asked what I think is a similar question involving the pgr_withpoints function (temporarily adding network nodes from a poi table). Maybe you could have look at that question first. http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/216273/52250

Comment: Thanks for the help JonasPedersen . This was my requirement. and John Barça for the effort.